Spherical Bessel and normal Bessel relation
I was looking at the recurrence relation of the Bessel function and was wondering if there is a way to have the step size more general, i.e., not $\pm 1$, but an arbitrary $\pm\beta$, where $\beta$ would be from $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.
I tried to look how the normal recurrence relation is derived, but that one is only applicable to $\beta\in\mathbb{N}$ (I guess multiple derivations would bring this up). Later, I tried to use the series expansion and to combine the terms of $J_{n-1}(x) + J_{n+1}(x)$ to obtain the terms of $J_n(x)$, but somehow I was not able to do it in an obvious way:
$$
J_{n-1}(x) + J_{n+1}(x) = 
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+(n-1)+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+(n-1)} + 
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+(n+1)+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+(n+1)} =
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+n}\left( \frac{2/x}{\Gamma(m+(n-1)+1)} + \frac{x/2}{\Gamma(m+(n+1)+1)} \right)=
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+n+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+n}\left( \frac{m+n}{x/2} + \frac{x/2}{m+n+1} \right) \\
\stackrel{!}{=} \\
\frac{2n}{x}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+n+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+n}
$$
If I could figure out why the $\stackrel{!}{=}$ holds, I would maybe try to generalize it for an arbitrary $\beta$.
I am trying to find this because I am currently computing something using the spherical Bessel functions implemented in Scipy, which are notorious for being slow (at least compared to the implementations in Matlab). I came across a Cuda implementation of the Bessel function with positive integer order and they are also available in python using Numba. My idea was to have a recurrence relation between $J_n$ and $j_n$, so I could precompute $J_n$ using Cuda and obtain $j_n$. For this, I tried setting $\beta=\frac{1}{2}$ to see what $J_{n-1/2}(x) + J_{n+1/2}(x)$ would look like, but to no avail.
Is there maybe a more elegant way of achieving this?
Another idea would be to look at the largest argument $x_{max}$ and build a linspace between $0$ and $x_{max}$ with $N$ points. Calculate the spherical Bessel function at those points and interpolate my needed values. This is a substantial speed-up, but I am unsure how large the error would be in that case!
